# ln -s: from one source to many destinations

Tags: symlink

Pseudocode

```
ln -s $HOME/file $HOME/Documents/ $HOME/Desktop/
```

where I want to create a symlink from the source to two destinations. 
Probably, `moreutils` and `pee`.

---

How can you create many symlinks from one source?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this with a single invocation of `ln`,but you could loop through all necessary destinations:

```
$ for i in "$HOME/Documents/" "$HOME/Desktop/"; do ln -s "$HOME/file" "$i"; done
```

Comment: You could omit the quotes if your home base directory does not contain spaces or other characters to be escaped, e.g. punctuation. However, using quotes always where appropriate makes a habit that keeps you from mistakes in other cases where directory/file names could easily contain special chars

Answer (score 6):

If you have `gnu parallel` you could try with

```
parallel ln -s /path/file {} ::: /path/dest1 /path/dest2 /path/dest3
```

or, to symlink multiple targets to (the same) multiple destinations

```
parallel ln -s {1} {2} ::: /path/file1 /path/file2 ::: /path/dest1 /path/dest2
```

Comment: @Masi Make sure you run the `parallel` command from the `parallel` package and not the one from `moreutils`.

Answer (score 5):

It's no less verbose than two separate `ln -s` invocations:

```
echo $HOME/Documents/ $HOME/Desktop/ | xargs -n 1 ln -s $HOME/file
```

but that only works for absolute paths (because symbolic links are interpreted relative to their parent directory, unless they're absolute).

(The relative cost drops of course as the number of links goes up. Also, this snippet relies on the fact that `$HOME` doesn't contain any spaces, tabs or newlines.)